Prevent backward tracing in iOS Drawing App (Swift)
I am using SwiftyDraw library to draw a path for my app. Drawing the path is working well but there is a problem if user start drawing path and move the finger back and forth in the same position. Still its drawing the path and it gets completed. Here I have my whole code.
lazy var targetView: UIView = {
    let sTargetView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                            y: 0,
                                            width: self.view.frame.width,
                                            height: self.view.frame.height/1.3))
    sTargetView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2,
                                 y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/2)
    sTargetView.backgroundColor = .clear
    sTargetView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    canvasView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
    sTargetView.addSubview(canvasView)
    canvasView.brush = .thick
    canvasView.brush.color =  self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn ? Color(.clear) : Color.init(self.accentColor)
    canvasView.frame = sTargetView.bounds
    canvasView.delegate = self
    return sTargetView
}()
var swiped = false
var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
var accentColor = UIColor.red//UIColor(hex: "00acc1")
let canvasView = SwiftyDrawView()
var isTutorialAnimationInProgresss = false

var strokeAnimationCounter = 0
var currentPathToTrace : CGPath!
var defaultTransform  = CGAffineTransform()
var assistiveDrawLayersArray = [CAShapeLayer()]
var pathToHitTestAgainst : CGPath!
let dashLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let tutorialLayer = CALayer()
var strokePathsArray = [MyBezierPath]()
var strokeIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        self.pathToHitTestAgainst = self.strokePathsArray[strokeIndex].cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0, transform: defaultTransform)
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var assistiveTouchSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidload() {
    self.view.addSubview(targetView)
    let p1 = MyBezierPath(svgPath: "M 55 20 V 90")
    let p2 = MyBezierPath(svgPath: "M 55 47 C 10 18 11 90 55 63")
    let p3 = MyBezierPath(svgPath: "M 55 47 C 93 25 94 62 71 73")
    let p4 = MyBezierPath(svgPath: "M 35 20 H 80")
    strokePathsArray.append(p1)
    strokePathsArray.append(p2)
    strokePathsArray.append(p3)
    strokePathsArray.append(p4)
    let combinedPath = CGMutablePath()
    combinedPath.addPath(p1.cgPath)
    combinedPath.addPath(p2.cgPath)
    combinedPath.addPath(p3.cgPath)
    combinedPath.addPath(p4.cgPath)
    defaultTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.targetView.frame.width/109, y: self.targetView.frame.width/109)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(defaultTransform)
    // The Bezier path that we made needs to be converted to
    // a CGPath before it can be used on a layer.
    shapeLayer.path = combinedPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.targetView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    self.pathToHitTestAgainst = self.strokePathsArray[0].cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 0, transform: defaultTransform)
    animatePath()
    setUpLayersForAssistiveMode(color: accentColor)
    self.targetView.layer.addSublayer(self.canvasView.layer)
}
func setUpLayersForAssistiveMode(color: UIColor){
    self.assistiveDrawLayersArray.removeAll()
    if self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn {
        self.strokePathsArray.forEach{
            let layer = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.path = $0.cgPath
            layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            layer.lineWidth = 6
            layer.strokeStart = 0
            layer.strokeEnd = 0
            layer.lineCap = .round
            layer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
            layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(defaultTransform)
            self.targetView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
            assistiveDrawLayersArray.append(layer)
        }
    }
}
func showHint(){
    let path = self.strokePathsArray[strokeIndex]
    dashLayer.path = path.cgPath
    dashLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    dashLayer.lineDashPattern =  [2,2]
    dashLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "pen")?.cgImage
    dashLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(defaultTransform)
    dashLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(hex: "f06292").cgColor
    dashLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
    self.currentPathToTrace = path.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .miter, miterLimit: 0, transform: defaultTransform)
    
    if let startPoint = path.startPoint {
        let circulPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: startPoint.x , y: startPoint.y) , radius: 1.5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2.0 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.path = circulPath.cgPath
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor(hex: "f06292").cgColor
        circleLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, 0)
        
        dashLayer.insertSublayer(circleLayer, at: 0)
    }
    
    let secondLastPoint =  path.cgPath.points().count>2 ?  path.cgPath.points()[path.cgPath.points().count-2] : path.cgPath.points()[0]
    
    if let lastPoint = path.cgPath.points().last {
        let angle = atan2((lastPoint.y - secondLastPoint.y), (lastPoint.x - secondLastPoint.x))
        
        let distance: CGFloat = 1.0
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: lastPoint)
        path.addLine(to: calculatePoint(from: lastPoint, angle: angle + CGFloat.pi/2, distance: distance)) // to the right
        path.addLine(to: calculatePoint(from: lastPoint, angle: angle, distance: distance)) // straight ahead
        path.addLine(to: calculatePoint(from: lastPoint, angle: angle - CGFloat.pi/2, distance: distance)) // to the left
        path.close()
        
        let  arrowHeadLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        arrowHeadLayer.path = path.cgPath
        arrowHeadLayer.lineWidth = 1
        arrowHeadLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(hex: "f06292").cgColor
        arrowHeadLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        dashLayer.insertSublayer(arrowHeadLayer, at: 1)
    }
}
func showTutorial(){
    if isTutorialAnimationInProgresss {return}   //avoid animation on repeated taps outside boundary
    
    let path = self.strokePathsArray[strokeIndex]
    self.tutorialLayer.opacity = 1
    tutorialLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "pen")?.cgImage
    
    tutorialLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    tutorialLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.repeatCount = 0 // just recommended by Apple
    animation.path = path.cgPath
    animation.calculationMode = .paced
    animation.beginTime = 0
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    isTutorialAnimationInProgresss = true
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        self.tutorialLayer.opacity = 0
        self.isTutorialAnimationInProgresss = false
    })
    tutorialLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
    dashLayer.addSublayer(tutorialLayer)
    self.targetView.layer.addSublayer(dashLayer)
}
func calculatePoint(from point: CGPoint, angle: CGFloat, distance: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: point.x + CGFloat(cosf(Float(angle))) * distance, y: point.y + CGFloat(sinf(Float(angle))) * distance)
}

func animatePath() {
    if strokeAnimationCounter == self.strokePathsArray.count { return }
    
    let layer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.strokeColor = self.accentColor.cgColor
    layer.lineWidth = 5.0
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 0
    layer.lineCap = .round
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(defaultTransform)
    layer.path = self.strokePathsArray[strokeAnimationCounter].cgPath
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0.0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    animation.duration = 1.0
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            print("ViewController was deallocated, stopping animation")
            return
        }
        
        strongSelf.strokeAnimationCounter += 1
        if strongSelf.strokeAnimationCounter <= strongSelf.strokePathsArray.count - 1 {
            strongSelf.animatePath()
        } else {
            strongSelf.canvasView.layer.sublayers?
                .filter { $0 is CAShapeLayer }
                .forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
            strongSelf.showHint()
            strongSelf.showTutorial()
        }
        print("Animation completed")
    }
    
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "myStroke")
    CATransaction.commit()
    
    self.canvasView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
class MyBezierPath: UIBezierPath {
var startPoint :CGPoint?

override func move(to point: CGPoint) {
    super.move(to: point)
    startPoint=point
}

}
extension CGPath {
func points() -> [CGPoint]{
    var bezierPoints = [CGPoint]()
    self.forEach(body: { (element: CGPathElement) in
        let numberOfPoints: Int = {
            switch element.type {
            case .moveToPoint, .addLineToPoint: // contains 1 point
                return 1
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint: // contains 2 points
                return 2
            case .addCurveToPoint: // contains 3 points
                return 3
            case .closeSubpath:
                return 0
            }
        }()
        for index in 0..<numberOfPoints {
            let point = element.points[index]
            bezierPoints.append(point)
        }
    })
    return bezierPoints
}

func forEach( body:@escaping @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
    typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
    func callback(info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, element: UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) {
        let body = unsafeBitCast(info, to: Body.self)
        body(element.pointee)
    }
    let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
    self.apply(info: unsafeBody, function: callback)
}}
extension DrawVC: SwiftyDrawViewDelegate{
func swiftyDraw(didCancelDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) {}

func swiftyDraw(shouldBeginDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func swiftyDraw(didBeginDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) {}

func swiftyDraw(isDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) {
    let point = touch.location(in: drawingView)
    let iscontain = pathToHitTestAgainst.contains(point)
    if iscontain  {
        //  print("contains")
        if self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn {
            if let first = self.currentPathToTrace.points().first{
                print("distamce:",   first.distance(to: point))
                print("length: ", currentPathToTrace.length/2)
                if first.distance(to: point)>=21 &&  assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd == 0  {
                    print("from right")
                    assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = 0
                    showTutorial()
                    return
                }
            }
            if let drawItem = drawingView.drawItems.last {
                let offset =     drawItem.path.length/(self.currentPathToTrace.length/2)
                //                    print(offset)
                if offset >= 0.9{
                    CATransaction.begin()
                    CATransaction.setDisableActions(false)
                    assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = 1
                    CATransaction.commit()
                    if strokeIndex == strokePathsArray.count-1{
                        dashLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                        dashLayer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
                        drawingView.clear()
                        return
                    }
                    dashLayer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
                    drawingView.clear()
                    self.strokeIndex+=1
                    showHint()
                    showTutorial()
                }else{
                    CATransaction.begin()
                    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
                    assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = offset
                    CATransaction.commit()
                    print("hello")
                }
            }
            return
        }
    }else{
        //            drawingView.undo()
        if self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn {
            if let drawItem = drawingView.drawItems.last {
                let offset =     drawItem.path.length/(self.currentPathToTrace.length/2)
                let progress =    Int(max(0, offset))
                //                    print (offset)
                if progress != 1{
                    assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = 0
                    drawingView.clear()
                    showTutorial()
                }
            }
            return
        }
        drawingView.undo()
        showTutorial()
    }
    //        print(drawingView.currentPoint)
}

func swiftyDraw(didFinishDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) {
    if self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn {
        if let drawItem = drawingView.drawItems.last {
            let offset =     drawItem.path.length/(self.currentPathToTrace.length/2)
            let progress =    Int(max(0, offset))
            //                    print("progress :", offset)
            if progress == 1{
                self.assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = 1
                if strokeIndex == strokePathsArray.count-1{
                    dashLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    dashLayer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
                    drawingView.clear()
                    return
                }
                dashLayer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
                drawingView.clear()
                self.strokeIndex+=1
                showHint()
                showTutorial()
            }else{
                //                        print("progress : \(progress)")
                drawingView.clear()
                self.showTutorial()
                assistiveDrawLayersArray[strokeIndex].strokeEnd = 0
            }
        }
        return
    }else{
        //        print(MyBezierPath(cgPath: strokePath!).length/2)
        if let drawItem = drawingView.drawItems.last{
            print(currentPathToTrace.length/2 - drawItem.path.length)
            if abs(currentPathToTrace.length/2 - drawItem.path.length) >= 17{
                drawingView.undo()
                showTutorial()
            } else {
                let layer = CAShapeLayer()
                layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                layer.lineWidth = 10
                layer.lineCap = .round
                layer.strokeColor = self.accentColor.cgColor
                layer.path = drawItem.path
                self.canvasView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
                
                drawingView.clear()
                
                dashLayer.sublayers?.filter{ $0 is CAShapeLayer }.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
                
                if strokeIndex == strokePathsArray.count-1{
                    dashLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    return
                }
                
                self.strokeIndex+=1
                showHint()
                showTutorial()
            }
        }
    }
}}

Above code is almost whole code to draw a path.
In func swiftyDraw(isDrawingIn drawingView: SwiftyDrawView, using touch: UITouch) this method in case of self.assistiveTouchSwitch.isOn = true condition I want to stop user from back tracing the already drawn path. I tried to check offset to prevent the thing but offset is never decreasing its value even if user draw backward.
I request any genius to resolve this issue for me. Thanks a lot.

You posted a whole BUNCH of code, along with a description of your problem that is hard to understand. I don't think anybody is going to be able to read several hundred lines of code and tell what you should change. You should create a minimum reproducible example, upload it to Github, and post a link to it in your question, along with a description of what is going wrong and how to reproduce the problem.

You didn't post the code for getting the .length of a path, but It appears you are trying to compare the length of the "trace" path to the user-drawn path. Several issues, including the fact that the user can draw this - https://i.sstatic.net/AJenqaZ8.png - staying inside pathToHitTestAgainst but drawing a much longer path. More likely, you'll want to use the distance to the next (or final) point. To avoid "back-tracing" keep track of the "closest" point drawn, and ignore new points that are farther away.

For paths consisting of only .addLine that won't be difficult. For paths with curves, though, you would need to calculate points "along the curve." As @DuncanC said ... Lots and lots of code there... You need to strip this down and work on a single task at a time.

https://github.com/Barhakhari/TracingApp.git
Here is the github link of my repo. Please review the code and give me solution.
Duncan C DonMag

@Sptibo - have you worked how to calculate points to track how far the user has traced the path? Or are you still looking for help?

@DonMag I have done nothing, I have shared you my repo. Please take a look at my code and try to resolve the issue. I tried it lot but even chatGPT cannot solve it for me.
